# Community Brought It Back The Question Was Useless To Begin With!

Tags: discussion

User [Community](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) just performed bump on a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50691/why-do-characters-keep-talking-after-dying-and-how-do-i-fix-it) that has [never](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hail_Sithis!) been an issue.

I have played Skyrim since December. I have tried and answered most questions and posed most questions of my own. This particular bug was never hit by ANYONE anywhere legitimately. Unless they are playing Razor1911's pirated release without the updates, they will never hit this particular bug.

I know I am not asking the right question here, but how do we prevent Community user's bumping for illegitimate, piracy questions?

Here is the required page [from UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hail_Sithis!).

I could be wrong here and way off base.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Just because the bug isn't listed on the UESP that makes the question about piracy?

Comment: If the question cannot or should not be closed, upvote one of the answers.  I don't believe Community bumps questions with upvoted answers.

Comment: How would Community know that the question is not worth bumping? It's more like a cron job than a person.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how do we prevent Community user's bumping for ill-legitimate, piracy questions?

We are going to have to wait for computers to gain consciousness and make their own decisions, but for now, the Community user only bumps open questions with no upvoted answers.

You can vote an answer and the question won't be bumped again.

(I'm not sure it's an illegitimate question though)

Comment: It's not a problem to ask questions! But, if you bring *this* up again, it'll just get closed as duplicate ;)